# p:autoComplete binding not showing label for searched value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I am trying to generate autocomplete box through binding. But I am not sure why label for the searched value is not rendered on UI. Code snippet is added below. Please help.

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
AutoComplete autoComplete = new AutoComplete();
ExpressionFactory factory = ExpressionFactory.newInstance();

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Class[] classes = new Class[1];
classes[0] = User.class;

autoComplete.setCompleteMethod(factory.createMethodExpression(facesContext.getELContext(), "#{userBean.values}", List.class , classes));
autoComplete.setVar("user");
autoComplete.setDropdown(false);
autoComplete.setItemValue(facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression("#{user}", User.class));
autoComplete.setItemLabel(facesContext.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(facesContext, "#{user.name}", String.class));
autoComplete.setConverter(new CommonConvertor());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up writing custom renderer in which wherever ItemLabel is referred I overridden the method & instead of using ItemLabel directly I put the EL expression evaluation whenever I find ItemLabel is starting with "#{". Which resulted in proper working of an autocomplete. The solution works.

I have overridden below methods

1. encodeInput
2. encodeMultipleMarkup
3. encodeSuggestionsAsTable
4. encodeSuggestionsAsList

Please let me know if you can find easier solution.